# How to fill an area outside spheres?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

The problem is the same as explained in my previous question: [How to fill an area outside circles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286981/how-to-fill-an-area-outside-circles). The only difference that now I need to fill the green area in **three-dimensional** space, i.e., the area outside both spheres but inside the cube.

At the moment I have:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.fillbetween,backgrounds}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=8cm, height=8cm,
    xmin=-0.2, xmax=1.2, ymin=-0.2, ymax=1.2, zmin=-0.2, zmax=1.2,
    every tick label/.append style={font=\tiny},
    xlabel = {$ x_1 $}, ylabel = {$ x_2 $}, zlabel = {$ x_3 $},
    xtick={0,0.167,0.33,0.5,0.66,0.833,1.0},
    xticklabels={$0$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{5}{6}$,$1$},
    ytick={0,0.167,0.33,0.5,0.66,0.833,1.0},
    yticklabels={$0$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{5}{6}$,$1$},
    ztick={0,0.167,0.33,0.5,0.66,0.833,1.0},
    zticklabels={$0$,$\frac{1}{6}$,$\frac{1}{3}$,$\frac{1}{2}$,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{5}{6}$,$1$},
    enlargelimits=0.05,
    view={15}{10},
]
% Draw hyper-rectangle (cube)
\addplot3[style=very thick,mark=none,color=blue] coordinates {
    (0,0,0) (1,0,0) (1,1,0)

    (0,0,1) (1,0,1) (1,1,1) (0,1,1) (0,0,1)

    (0,0,0) (0,0,1)

    (1,0,0) (1,0,1)

    (1,1,0) (1,1,1)
};

% Draw imaginary edges
\addplot3[style=dashed,style=thick,mark=none,color=blue] coordinates { 
    (1,1,0) (0,1,0) (0,0,0)

    (0,1,0) (0,1,1)
};

% Draw sampling points
\addplot3[only marks,mark=*,nodes near coords,point meta=explicit symbolic, color=blue, opacity=0.75,font=\scriptsize] coordinates {
    (1/3,1/3,1/3) [(1)]
    (2/3,2/3,2/3) [(2)]
};

% Draw the first sphere, based on:
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124916/draw-sphere-pgfplots-with-axis-at-center
\addplot3[%
    opacity = 0.3,
    mesh,
    red,
    z buffer = sort,
    samples = 21,
    variable = \u,
    variable y = \v,
    domain = 0:180,
    y domain = 0:360,
] ({0.33 + 0.58*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {0.33 + 0.58*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {0.33 + 0.58*cos(v)});

% Draw the second sphere
\addplot3[%
    opacity = 0.3,
    mesh,
    red,
    z buffer = sort,
    samples = 21,
    variable = \u,
    variable y = \v,
    domain = 0:180,
    y domain = 0:360,
] ({0.66 + 0.58*cos(u)*sin(v)}, {0.66 + 0.58*sin(u)*sin(v)}, {0.66 + 0.58*cos(v)});

% Draw diameter
\addplot3[color=black,very thick] coordinates { (1/3,1/3,1/3) (0,0,0) } node[pos=0.5, yshift=8pt, sloped] { $\delta$};

% TODO: Fill the area outside both spheres but inside the cube

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produce:
[image]

I am wondering if there is a similar way to @Alenanno proposed [solution for 2-D case](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/286986/93179).

Comment: If you mean ALL the volume outside the spheres then you need the circles where the spheres intersect the box and each other (3 circles, or possibly arcs around corners.

Answer (score 2):

An approach using [Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/andrew-stacey)'s [spath3](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) Ti*k*Z library. I'm only drawing one sphere as an example.

We need to create four paths: sphere and three arcs of intersection between it and the cube faces. Then we calculate all the intersections, and we weld them watching the order carefully (there are a lot of paths after splitting them).

Like this:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,intersections,perspective,spath3}

\tikzset
{% styles
   xy/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=1},
   xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=1},
   yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=1},
   sphere/.style={red,ball color=red,shading=ball,fill opacity=#1},
   cube/.style 2 args={draw,fill=gray!#1,fill opacity=#2}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,
                    3d view={125}{30},scale=2]
% radii
\pgfmathsetmacro\br{sqrt(1/3)}         % sphere radius
\pgfmathsetmacro\lr{sqrt(\br*\br-1/9)} % intersection circles radius
% paths
\path[spath/save=S] % sphere
     (2/3,2/3,2/3) circle [radius=\br cm];
\path[xy,spath/save=Ixy] % intersection xy plane
     (1,1/3) arc (315:135:\lr);
\path[xz,spath/save=Ixz] % intersection xz plane
     (1,1/3) arc (315:135:\lr);
\path[yz,spath/save=Iyz] % intersection yz plane
     (1,1/3) arc (315:135:\lr);
\tikzset
{% spath3 operatios
   spath/remove empty components={S},
   spath/split at intersections={S}{Ixy},
   spath/split at intersections={S}{Ixz},
   spath/split at intersections={S}{Iyz},
   spath/get components of={S}\SPcpts,
   spath/get components of={Ixy}\XYcpts,
   spath/get components of={Ixz}\XZcpts,
   spath/get components of={Iyz}\YZcpts,
}
% axes
\draw[-latex](0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex](0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[below] {$y$};
\draw[-latex](0,0,0) -- (0,0,2) node[above] {$z$};
% sphere, non-visible parts
\draw[sphere=0.8,%
      spath/use= \getComponentOf\SPcpts{5} ,
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{6} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\YZcpts{9} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XYcpts{1} ,weld},
     ];
\draw[sphere=0.8,%
      spath/use= \getComponentOf\SPcpts{18} ,
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XYcpts{6} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XZcpts{7} ,weld,reverse},
     ];
\draw[sphere=0.8,%
      spath/use= \getComponentOf\SPcpts{13} ,
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XZcpts{1} ,weld,reverse},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\YZcpts{1} ,weld},
     ];
% center
\fill[red] (2/3,2/3,2/3) circle (0.15mm);
% cube
\draw[cube={50}{0.8},xy] (1/3,1) arc (135:315:\lr) |- (0,0) |- cycle;
\draw[cube={80}{0.8},xz] (1/3,1) arc (135:315:\lr) |- (0,0) |- cycle;
\draw[cube={65}{0.8},yz] (1/3,1) arc (135:315:\lr) |- (0,0) |- cycle;
\draw (1,1,1) -- (1/3,1,1);
\draw (1,1,1) -- (1,1/3,1);
\draw (1,1,1) -- (1,1,1/3);
% sphere, visible part
\draw[sphere=0.8,%
      spath/use= \getComponentOf\SPcpts{1} ,
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{2} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{3} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{4} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{5} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XYcpts{1} ,weld,reverse},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\YZcpts{9} ,weld,reverse},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{7} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{8} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{9} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{10},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{11},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{12},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\YZcpts{1} ,weld,reverse},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XZcpts{1} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{14},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{15},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{16},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\SPcpts{17},weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XZcpts{7} ,weld},
      spath/use={\getComponentOf\XYcpts{6} ,weld,reverse},
     ];
% tangent point
\fill (1,1,1) circle (0.15mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Or, changing all the opacity to 1 in all the surfaces:

[image]